# How do I set the scale to be static insteal of dynamic when using ggplot2's plot_usmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to have my legend's scale be consistent across nine different plots. Currently the scale changes for each plot.
Here is the code for the first two plots:

```
plot_usmap(data = january, values="tot_cases", color="black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", name = "Total Cases", label = scales::comma,) +
  theme(legend.position = "right",panel.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "lightblue"))

plot_usmap(data = february, values="tot_cases", color="black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", name = "Total Cases", label = scales::comma) +
  theme(legend.position = "right",panel.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "lightblue"))
```

How can I get the scales to be the same for all my plots?

Comment: Where does `plot_usmap` come from?

Comment: Try setting the same range via the `limits` argument inside `scale_fill_gradient2`.

Comment: @camille I think it comes from the "usmap" package

Answer (score 0):

Like @stefan said, add the limits parameter which takes 2 numbers, min and max.
plot_usmap(data = january, values="tot_cases", color="black") +
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", name = "Total Cases", label = scales::comma, limits = c(MIN, MAX)) +
theme(legend.position = "right",panel.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "lightblue"))